# What does *__errno()= some value mean?

Tags: c++, error-handling, operating-system

So i am trying to understand simple OS system calls and stumbled upon this line of code witch i don't know what it means : `*__errno()= msg.error.number;`. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely a multithreaded version of `errno` defined in errno.h.

`__errno()` call will return a pointer to the thread local `int`,
 and `*__errno()= msg.error.number;` will write into that `int`.

That should normally be wrapped in a macro, so you don't see the call or dereference.